# Destructing array of objects into one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a result like this.

```
[ [ { _id: 5e0e46938d6bb7459407ad8b,
      accountId: 58dc5b9f3107602dbaba1281,
      buildingId: 5d254bb179584ebcbb68b712,
      gatewayId: 5d254b64ba574040d9632ada,
      deviceId: 5d25f9d2dc4aea7838b0aaa1,
      movementIndex: 2.437685743915776,
      fallStatus: 6,
      breathingRate: 21,
      breathingStatus: 1,
      presenceStatus: 1,
      heartRate: 88,
      heartRateStatus: 1,
      noMovementPeriod: 3,
      __v: 0,
      createdAt: 2020-01-02T19:37:55.423Z,
      updatedAt: 2020-01-02T19:37:55.423Z } ],
  [ { _id: 5e0e46678d6bb7459407ad76,
      accountId: 58dc5b9f3107602dbaba1281,
      buildingId: 5d254bb179584ebcbb68b712,
      gatewayId: 5d254b64ba574040d9632ada,
      deviceId: 5d25f9d2dc4aea7838b0aaa2,
      movementIndex: 2.079566889716151,
      fallStatus: 1,
      breathingRate: 18,
      breathingStatus: -1,
      presenceStatus: 0,
      heartRate: 92,
      heartRateStatus: -1,
      noMovementPeriod: 2,
      __v: 0,
      createdAt: 2020-01-02T19:37:11.972Z,
      updatedAt: 2020-01-02T19:37:11.972Z } ],

   ]
```

As you can see they are separate objects.
I want them to be in one single object as elements so I can have only one array of object.

Expected result -

```
[ { _id: 5e0e46938d6bb7459407ad8b,
    accountId: 58dc5b9f3107602dbaba1281,
    buildingId: 5d254bb179584ebcbb68b712,
    gatewayId: 5d254b64ba574040d9632ada,
    deviceId: 5d25f9d2dc4aea7838b0aaa1,
    movementIndex: 2.437685743915776,
    fallStatus: 6,
    breathingRate: 21,
    breathingStatus: 1,
    presenceStatus: 1,
    heartRate: 88,
    heartRateStatus: 1,
    noMovementPeriod: 3,
    __v: 0,
    createdAt: 2020-01-02T19:37:55.423Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-01-02T19:37:55.423Z },
 { _id: 5e0e46678d6bb7459407ad76,
    accountId: 58dc5b9f3107602dbaba1281,
    buildingId: 5d254bb179584ebcbb68b712,
    gatewayId: 5d254b64ba574040d9632ada,
    deviceId: 5d25f9d2dc4aea7838b0aaa2,
    movementIndex: 2.079566889716151,
    fallStatus: 1,
    breathingRate: 18,
    breathingStatus: -1,
    presenceStatus: 0,
    heartRate: 92,
    heartRateStatus: -1,
    noMovementPeriod: 2,
    __v: 0,
    createdAt: 2020-01-02T19:37:11.972Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-01-02T19:37:11.972Z } ]
```

I am trying to figure out a lodash but not getting any result. 
Your help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is your first snippet two different variables?  Or is that one long string?  Because that's invalid JSON

Comment: Please check now. I updated my snippet in question. thanks

Comment: Ah, so you have an array of arrays with an object in them.  You're looking for a `flatten` in lodash if they have it.  https://lodash.com/docs/2.4.2#flatten

Answer (score 3):

You can just use [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and it will work fine for you, no need to loop

```js
const data = [[{_id:"5e0 e46938d6bb7459407ad8b",accountId:"58 dc5b9f3107602dbaba1281",buildingId:"5 d254bb179584ebcbb68b712",gatewayId:"5 d254b64ba574040d9632ada",deviceId:"5 d25f9d2dc4aea7838b0aaa1",movementIndex:2.437685743915776,fallStatus:6,breathingRate:21,breathingStatus:1,presenceStatus:1,heartRate:88,heartRateStatus:1,noMovementPeriod:3,__v:0,createdAt:"2020 - 01 - 02 T19: 37: 55.423 Z",updatedAt:"2020 - 01 - 02 T19: 37: 55.423 Z"}],[{_id:"5e0 e46678d6bb7459407ad76",accountId:"58 dc5b9f3107602dbaba1281",buildingId:"5 d254bb179584ebcbb68b712",gatewayId:"5 d254b64ba574040d9632ada",deviceId:"5 d25f9d2dc4aea7838b0aaa2",movementIndex:2.079566889716151,fallStatus:1,breathingRate:18,breathingStatus:-1,presenceStatus:0,heartRate:92,heartRateStatus:-1,noMovementPeriod:2,__v:0,createdAt:"2020 - 01 - 02 T19: 37: 11.972 Z",updatedAt:"2020 - 01 - 02 T19: 37: 11.972 Z"}]];
const newData = data.flat();

console.log(newData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your original post is a bit unclear, but I think you have an array, inside of which are subarrays with a single object in them each? Sort of like this?

```
var foo = [
    [ { bar: "baz" } ],
    [ { bar: "qux" } ]
];
```

There is no syntactic sugar ("destructuring" shorthand) you can do to flatten that, that I know of. But it's quite simple with `Array.map()`:

```
var baz = foo.map(ea => ea[0]);
// baz = [ { bar: "baz" }, { bar: "qux"} ]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: this is perfect. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution using destructuring

```
const arr1 = [[{......}], [{......}]]

const result = [...arr1[0], ...arr1[1]]
```

Comment: It's an array of arrays